# Symfony2 404 error: Object Not Found (ParamConverter error)

Tags: php, symfony, parameters, controller, http-status-code-404

I created a new boundary class called search.html.twig, but when I go to the URL (http://localhost:8000/shrubs/search) I get the following error:

> ERROR - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "AppBundle\Entity\Shrubs object not found." at C:\Users\rosmith\shrub_search\vendor\sensio\framework-extra-bundle\Request\ParamConverter\DoctrineParamConverter.php line 66

There must be something wrong with my ParamConverter? Are my annotations correct? I read the symfony documentation but it just doesn't make sense to me. Here's my controller:

```
 /**
     * Finds and displays a shrub entity.
     *
     * @Route("/search", name="shrubs_search")
     * @ParamConverter("post", class="AppBundle:Shrubs")
     */
    private function searchAction(Request $request)
    {
        $shrub = new Shrubs();
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ShrubsType', $shrub)
            ->add('botanicalname', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Botanical Name:'))
            ->add('commonname', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Common Name:'))
            ->add('wetsoil', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Tolerates Wet Soil:'))
            ->add('moistsoil', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Prefers Moist Soil:'))
            ->add('peatysoil', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Prefers Peaty Soil:'))
            ->add('welldrainedsoil', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Prefers Well-drained Soil:'))
            ->add('drought', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Tolerates Drought:'))
            ->add('claysoil', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Tolerates Clay Soil:'))
            ->add('sandysoil', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Prefers Sandy Soil:'))
            ->add('loamsoil', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Prefers Loam Soil:'))
            ->add('infertilesoil', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Tolerates Infertile Soil:'))
            ->add('richsoil', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Prefers Rich Soil:'))
            ->add('compactedsoil', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Tolerates Compacted Soil:'))
            ->add('cityconditions', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Tolerates City Conditions:'))
            ->add('pollution', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Tollerates Pollution:'))
            ->add('salt', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Tolerates Salt Conditions:'))
            ->add('windy', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Tolerates Windy Conditions:'))
            ->add('shade', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Prefers Shade:'))
            ->add('partshade', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Prefers Part Shade:'))
            ->add('fullsun', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Prefers Full Sun:'))
            ->add('pestproblem', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Pest Problem:'))
            ->add('borderlinehardy', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'BorderLine Hardy'));

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($shrub);
            $em->flush($shrub);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('shrubs_show', array('id' => $shrub->getNumber()));
        }

        return $this->render('shrubs/new.html.twig', array(
            'shrub' => $shrub,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

Comment: simply remove the paramconverter annotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route should contain `post` param.

```
@Route("/search/{post}", name="shrubs_search")
```

Also your method should take this param as method argument.

Comment: i changed the annotation to:

Comment: /**
     * Finds and displays a shrub entity.
     *
     * @Route("/search/{post}", name="shrubs_search")
     * @ParamConverter("post", class="AppBundle:Shrubs")
     */

Comment: the URL posted in the question don't specify any id so probably is only a typo and don't really need a paramconverter here

Comment: It's the same error, even  if I remove the paramcoverter part

Comment: I just have this annotation: @Route("/search", name="shrubs_search")

Comment: If you still face the same error even if I remove the paramcoverter part, it looks like cache problem.

Comment: I try with and without post

Comment: I did clear the cache. Really scratching my head here

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. I had to change the controller method from private to public. Thank you both so much for your help

Comment: I have a same problem: 2 almost equals, public function, 2 vars in, object and string. One can find Entity obj, other can't find the tame entity   lol